# Break test if "if-statement" fail

Tags: selenium, if-statement, logic, protractor, mocha.js

one question about if statement using webdriverjs/protractor (very similar). See the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e95affba5f7e148c553e772e1962073b

Note that the function **it('should search for rut and click in send push', function (done)**​ does an if statement if the button is present on the screen, but my question is: If the button IS NOT present on the screen, how can I stop the test? That is, as not performing the function ​**it('should send message', function (done)​** ?

Answer (score 0):

use `expect()` method inside your test to check if button id displayed in the webpage or not. if `expect()` method `fails` then protractor will not execute the next step in that test.

```
expect(element(by.css("button")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy()
element(by.css("button")).click() //this line will not be executed if the above validation fails
```

Comment: In fact if don't appears the button is not a fail, is a normal behavior in web. So if the button don't appears, I would like to simply close test without fail